# Llamar un api-rest desde un estado de BloC

Tags: firebase, flutter, login

Hola estoy realizando un login con firebase pero con el uid del usuario deseo consultar un api-rest y si trae datos significa que está registrado y muestra una pantalla caso contrario muestra otra pantalla

```
Future<void> _authStateChanged(AuthUser? user) async {
try {
  final usuario = 'uWb0PKBbhBZVirLh0bllk2ncDRp1hhhh';
  final dataSource = RestDataSourceMySql();
  final result = await dataSource.getName(usuario);

  if (user != null && result != null) {
    print('trajo datos');
    print(result);
    emit(AuthSignedWithMysql(user));
  } else if (user != null && result == null) {
    emit(AuthNoRegister(user));
  } else if (user == null) {
    emit(AuthSignedOut());
  }
} on Exception catch (_) {
  print("Se cayo");
}
```

Si trae datos me presenta la nueva pantalla sin problemas, pero si trae el uid y en el api rest no trae nada me sale este mensaje "RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)"

Comment: Ey, ¿Qué tal? Tienes varias preguntas que has realizado y te han respondido, pero no has marcado la respuesta correcta. ¿Qué te parecería hacerlo? De esa forma, fomentas que el buen uso del foro y cumples sus reglas. Y en caso de que las preguntas no satisfagan tu respuesta, quizás podrías aportar algo más de información. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preámbulo. Un pequeño consejo.**

La verdad que estás dando muy poca información referente al error. Además, todavía, en el momento en el que escribo esta respuesta tienes preguntas sin marcar una respuesta correcta. Recuerda que al hacerlo, fomentas el buen uso del sitio. Si sientes que no hay respuesta correcta para tu pregunta, quizás deberías añadir más información a la misma.

Deberías exponer la parte del código relativa al problema. Ahí hay solo un método, el cual no deja entrever desde dónde/o cómo quieres llamar al método.

Las partes relativas al código en este caso, podrían ser el Bloc que estás usando para llamar al método, pero solo el Bloc y dicho método.

**Respuesta**
Creo que estás usando `Flutter_Bloc`, que no es lo mismo que el patrón `BloC`, lo que puede llevar a confusión, ya que dicho patrón se puede implementar con cualquier gestor de estado.

Normalmente, en estos casos lo que se hace es que el Bloc reciba al repositorio como una dependencia. Algo así:

```dart
class MyBloc extends Bloc<MyEvent, MyState> {
  ApiRest apiRest;
  
  MyBloc(this.apiRest) : super(MyInitial()) {
   
  }
}
```

Y ahora, dentro del bloc, podrías llamar a dicho repositorio para consultar la información del usuario, gracias al UID que te llega por parámetro del método:

```dart
// Hacemos la función asíncrona para poder hacer peticiones a la 
// api rest y poder esperar el resultado.
Future<void> _authStateChanged(AuthUser? user) async {
    if (user == null) {
        emit(AuthSignedOut());
        return;
    }
    
    // probablemente, la operación es asíncrona y necesitamos esperar
    // el resultado. 
    final result = await apiRest.checkIfUserExist(user!.id);

    // Proceder a emitir estado si el usuario está registrado
    // o si no lo está.
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu valiosa ayuda, soy nuevo en esto de stackoverflow y parece que si he seleccionado como respuesta util a las anteriores y respuesta correcta,

Comment: voy a revisar bien tu sugerencia para ver si puedo completar mi mision

Comment: he realizado las sugerencias que me indicas y ya me presentaria la pantalla donde está registrado, pero cuando no trae datos del api-rest me da error, he modificado la pregunta

Comment: Ni idea de porqué puede ser. Usa el depurador del IDE que estés usando y busca de dónde proviene el error. Tienes un try -catch en ese método, así que no creo que el error esté en dicho método, sino que es más probable que sea por algo que se invoca en otro lugar.